# Links to element IDs not working in Safari + React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, safari, anchor

I am developing a simple single-page website with React.

On top of the page I have a menu bar, with links to certain parts of the page:

```
    <li><a href="/#about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#team">Team</a></li>
```

The parts of my page (not necessarily components) have the corresponding ID attribute, eg:

```
...
        <div id="about" className="rn-about-area ptb--120 bg_color--5">          
             ... <CONTENT>
        </div>
```

When a link in the menu bar gets clicked, the page should jump to the corresponding part of the page. The problem: The links are working in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari.

What I tried so far based on similar StackOverflow questions (that are over ten years old):

- Omitting the / before the #anchor:
  `<li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>`
- Defining the absolute URL path to each anchor:
  `<li><a href="https://myURL.com/#about">About us</a></li>`
- Implementing methods like scrollTo() or scrollIntoView()
- Wrapping the anchor-elements in React  components
- Checking for redirects that may cause problems using https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

but nothing works.

Is there any other way I could try? If not, my only idea is to destructure the page into seperate pages, so I can link them without using anchors.

EDIT: There might be an issue with React and the way the website is set up, because I checked a similar page, created without React, and there the first mentioned approach works, also in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in fact a React problem:

Using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) it finally works now!